# What is the difference between kernelBase.dll and Kernel32.dll

Tags: windows, dll, winapi

What is the difference between kernelBase.dll and Kernel32.dll in system32 folder ?

Why both of them implement `WideCharToMultiByte` ?

Comment: The explanation is great, but a small semantic pointer, actually kernel32.dll and advapi.dll get functionalities from kernelbase.dll.
eg: kenerl32!WriteProcessMemoryStub is traced to KERNELBASE!WriteProcessMemory, as already pointed.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is the reason why there are some WinAPIs that also existing in kernelbase.dll.

"As an example of functionality that we moved to low-level binaries, kernelbase.dll gets functionality from kernel32.dll and advapi32.dll. This means that the existing binary now forwards calls down to the new binary rather than handling them directly; the forwarding can be static (the export table shows the redirection), or runtime (the dll has a stub routine that calls down to the new binary). This will impact low-level applications such as security and backup applications that are dependent upon internal APIs and offsets."

Reference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Win7AppQual/new-low-level-binaries

See the example below.

This is the disassembly of OpenProcess in Kernel32.dll which redirects the OpenProcess to Kernelbase.dll
[image]

Disassembly of OpenProcess in Kernelbase.dll that call the Native API NTOpenProcess

[image]

Comment: is the edirected via `ApiSetShema.dll` ? from which Windows's version is that happend?

Comment: I provided a screenshot for the kernel32 and kernelbase. Starting from Windows 7.

Comment: Im sorry for not adding the further explanation in the screenshot, I just want to show you that the OpenProcess in kernel32.dll is actually points to the OpenProcess of kernelbase.dll  that calls the NtOpenProcess.

Comment: that very intresting what you preset,  do you say that all function in `Kernel32.dll` redirect to `Kernelbase.dl` ? how can I please see it in your screenshot? you put screenshot of `OpenProcess` function in `Kernel32.dll and `OpenProcess` in `Kernelbase.dl` , how can I see the redirection?

Comment: @Lolo9876 I created a small program that use the OpenProcess. https://imgur.com/a/6Gw2zbQ